# How are tag scores calculated?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-score

Someone asked a question tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php), [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie) and [setcookie](/questions/tagged/setcookie). I answered the question. The answer was accepted and up-voted by the asker. Now my [php](/questions/tagged/php) score (in my profile) has increased by one, but my score in the other two tags did not change.

How does scoring of tags work? Do answers count only for the first tag used on a question?

(Note: the other tag scores increased less than two hours after this question was asked.)

Comment: The tag scores in your profile aren't updated immediately (either it's cached or the scores are recalculated every so often - I don't know). Check again in an bit.

Comment: @Mat but the score against the PHP updated immediately

Comment: Did you scroll to the second page of tags in your profile? That is the group in which the `cookies` tag is currently displayed.  It's possible they changed at the same time, but just weren't in view.

Comment: @jonsca I scrolled other pages dude

Comment: @jonsca its updated now. Updated for both tags

Comment: @Mat its updated now. Updated for both tags

Comment: must have been the cache, dont know if common tags get updated more frequently - like `php`, `java` and so on compared to `cookies`