# Remove 1.25 maximum ratio for suggesting tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I discovered that there is the tag [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262), which is the same as [ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript). So I decided to suggest a synonym.

**Round One**. I tried to suggest [ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript) as a synonym of [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262). I got "*The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!*".

**Round two**. OK, it seems that StackOverflow thinks that [ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript) doesn't exists because it's a synonym of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Then, I tried to add [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) as a synonym of [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262). But my score in [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) tag was 0, so I couldn't (see [Remove tag score requirement for suggesting synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161971/remove-tag-score-requirement-for-suggesting-synonyms)).

**Round three**. OK, maybe I don't have [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) score, but my [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) score is high. Then, I tried to add [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) as a synonym of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). I got "*Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators*" (see [Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators)).

**Round four**. OK, maybe I don't have any [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) score but I could gain it. So I edited added the tag [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) to the question [Relocating text with js code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205839/relocating-text-with-js-code/12205867#12205867) because my answer has 11 upvotes, and this way gaining 11 [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) score. But my [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) score was still 0 (see [How are tag scores calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/how-are-tag-scores-calculated)).

**Round five**. After some hours, my [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) score was updated. And I tried to add *javascript* as a synonym of [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) again. But now I get "*Can't create synonym; the 'javascript' tag appears more than 1.25 times the 'ecma262' tag*".

So I have lost 5 rounds and I give up because StackOverflow has totally defeated me.

Comment: I see your frustration.

Comment: All of the uses of ecma262 appear to be by users wishing to specifically state the version of Javascript they are running.  [status-declined].

Comment: Never give up! Never surrender!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, wouldn't that be making Javascript a sub-tag of ecma262? E.g. something extremely bad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Round One**

This round shouldn't have even happened. Tag synonyms work by sending a synonym tag to a *master tag*. You should always be on the master tag when suggesting a synonym, because any uses of the synonym automatically get retagged to its master. The [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) tag would not be considered the master tag in this case, so you should instead be trying to suggest a synonym on the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

**Round Two**

Again, this round shouldn't happen. You need to be on the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to be suggesting the synonym.

**Round Three**

This is where your legitimate concern is. The system thinks that [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) is a version-specific tag and thus won't let you create it. In these cases, you should come to Meta to discuss whether or not it should be synonymized with the master tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (like you have).

**Round Four**

There was no need to gain the required score in the [ecma262](/questions/tagged/ecma262) tag, you only needed the required score in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

**Round Five**

The ratio is there for a reason - so that low-count tags don't become masters of high-count tags. Again, this occurred because you were trying to suggest the synonym on the wrong tag. There is no reason to remove the limit.

***See Also:*** [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about master/slave synonym tags.

Answer (score 4):

ECMAScript is a politically correct name for JavaScript.

ECMA262 is the standard upon which JavaScript is based.

They're not synonyms. Questions about the ECMA-262 standard are *rare*. Questions about JavaScript/ECMAScript are common as mud.

The behavior of the system exists to make sure folks who aren't familiar with the specifics of tags don't make bad assumptions and break things. I have to say, that seems to have worked here.

Comment: I don't see the difference. All questions about JavaScript should ask (more or less explicitly) something about the standards. I can't imagine a question like "*I hate using `function` keyword to declare functions, which nonstandard alternative supported by X (strange browser) do I have?*"

Comment: Rather than rehashing it, I'm gonna refer you to [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60417/desynonymize-ecmascript-tag) which led to the retagging of a handful of ecmascript questions with either [ecma262] or [ecmascript-5]. But to summarize: no, most folks *don't* care what the standard says should work - they want a solution that'll actually work in whatever popular browsers their users rely on.