# ECMAScript tag should not go to javascript

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we please remove the forward that forwards [ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript) to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?

Javascript is an **implemenation** of ECMAScript -- they are not the same thing.
[See the ECMAScript wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).

A square is a rhombus but a rhombus is **not** a square as to: 
Javascript is ECMAScript but ECMAScript is **not** Javascript

Related old rejected request: [Desynonymize [ecmascript] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60417/241700)

Comment: Can you explain what makes this a different question to the one that [you linked to as related?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60417/desynonymize-ecmascript-tag) It hasn't been rejected, it just hasn't been fully actionned. You can always add a bounty on that one to get it more attention.

Comment: @JonW a mod [basically rejected it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60493/241700)

Comment: Not exactly. If it had been totally rejected then it would be tagged as `[tag:status-declined]`

Comment: @qwertynl: Reasoning still applies, no?

Comment: K adding a bounty @SpecialSnowflake

Comment: The problem with this question (and the old one) is that they're virtual. Can we have an example of a question where this synonymization was a problem ?

Comment: What do you mean @dystroy ?

Comment: Bountying the question isn't going to change this, @qwertynl - that battle was lost years ago, when the folks *actually using the site* repeatedly failed to consistently differentiate between JavaScript, ActionScript and ECMAScript. We put a fair bit of effort into separating out the questions that *weren't* specific to an implementation into the [ecma262] tag, but even that would've been synonymized by now if [the system didn't actively block folks from doing so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170076/remove-1-25-maximum-ratio-for-suggesting-tag-synonyms).